# Issues with scrollbar to window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I'm trying to insert scrollbar in a window (tkinter) but it doesn't work.

Below is the code I use to insert the scrollbar.

I'm using tk.canvas and ttk.Scrollbar.

When I put this line (self.second_frame_outlier.pack(fill='both')#,padx =20,pady=10)) in comment the scrollbar seems to work but the buttons don't appear.

Any idea how can I fix this?

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd          
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import HORIZONTAL
from tkinter import BOTH, Menu, END
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from tkinter import messagebox
from os import path
from tkinter import IntVar
import sys
import os
class Mainframe(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)    
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomeFrame,Project_Targets):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("HomeFrame")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        
        
#%%
class HomeFrame(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        label = tk.Label(self,text="App", fg="Black", font=("Franklin Gothic Medium", 25)).pack(pady=20)
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Hello " + os.getlogin() + ", how are you today?", fg="Grey", font=("Franklin Gothic Medium", 15)).pack(pady=20)
        menubar = Menu(self.controller)
        self.controller.config(menu=menubar)
        targets = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)        
        targets.add_command(label="New", command=lambda:controller.show_frame("Project_Targets"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Country City", menu=targets)        
class Project_Targets(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        global lista_combobox,df_matriz_target,category
        lista_combobox = []
        category = {'Portugal':'Lisbon','Spain':'Madrid','France':'Paris','England':'London'}
        label = tk.Label(self,text="App - Country City", fg="Black", font=("Franklin Gothic Medium", 25)).pack(pady=20)
        
        self.wrapper = tk.LabelFrame(self)
        self.wrapper.pack(fill='both',padx =20,pady=10)
        #criar scrollbar geral
        self.my_canvas_targets = tk.Canvas(self.wrapper)        
        self.my_scrollbar_targets = ttk.Scrollbar(self.wrapper, orient='vertical', command=self.my_canvas_targets.yview)
        self.my_scrollbar_targets.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')
        
        self.my_canvas_targets.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill='both',expand=1)
        self.my_canvas_targets.configure(yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar_targets.set)
        self.my_canvas_targets.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.my_canvas_targets.configure(scrollregion = self.my_canvas_targets.bbox("all")))        
        
        self.second_frame_outlier = tk.Frame(self.my_canvas_targets)           
        self.my_canvas_targets.create_window((0,0), window=self.second_frame_outlier, anchor="nw")       
        self.second_frame_outlier.pack(fill='both',padx =20,pady=10)
        
        #frame dos project and campaign
        self.frame_main = tk.LabelFrame(self.second_frame_outlier,text = 'Country - City')
        self.frame_main.pack(fill='both',padx =20,pady=10)       
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame_main,text="Step 1 - Select your Country ")
        self.label.pack(pady=10)
        self.box_3 = ttk.Combobox(self.frame_main,width = 20, values = list(category.keys()))
        self.box_3.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.getUpdateData)
        self.box_3.pack(pady=5)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame_main,text="Step 2 - Select your City (Optional)")
        self.label.pack(pady=10)
        self.box_2 = ttk.Combobox(self.frame_main, width = 35)
        self.box_2.pack()
        self.btt_continue = ttk.Button(self.frame_main, text='Continue', command=self.save_values)
        self.btt_continue.pack(pady=5)
        
        d = {'Country': ['Portugal','Spain','France','England'], 'City': ['Lisbon','Madrid','Paris','London'],'Age':[24,34,32,41],'School':[1,2,3,4],'Sex':[1,2,1,1],'SNS':[122,233,232,202]}
        df_matriz_target = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
       
        
        #criar frame treeview
        self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.second_frame_outlier,text = 'Table Targets')
        self.frame.pack(fill='both',padx =20,pady=10)
        #lista das columns names 
        table_columns=list(df_matriz_target.columns)
        #criar tabela
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875343/how-to-implement-tkinter-scrollbars
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.frame,columns=table_columns, show="headings",height = 10)#,height=9)#len(table_date))
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set, yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        # self.tree.pack()
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.NS)
        self.hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #criar haedings
        for col in table_columns:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title())
        #criar frame add  update
        self.second_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.second_frame_outlier,text = 'Add or Update')
        self.second_frame.pack(fill='both',padx =20,pady=10)
        self.label_dir = tk.Label(self.second_frame,text="Step 1 - Choose the folder 1:")
        self.label_dir.pack(pady=10)
        self.label_dir2 = tk.Label(self.second_frame,text="Step 1 - Choose the 2:")
        self.label_dir2.pack(pady=10)
        self.label_dir3 = tk.Label(self.second_frame,text="Step 1 - Choose the 3:")
        self.label_dir3.pack(pady=10)
        self.label_dir4 = tk.Label(self.second_frame,text="Step 1 - Choose the 4:")
        self.label_dir4.pack(pady=10)
        self.label_dir5 = tk.Label(self.second_frame,text="Step 1 - 5:")
        self.label_dir5.pack(pady=10)
        
    def getUpdateData(self,  event):
        '''
        Funcao de atualizacao das comboboxes Country and City
        '''
        if lista_combobox ==[]:
            lista_combobox.append(1)
            self.box_2['values'] = category[self.box_3.get()]
        else:
            #apagar a campaign caso se mude de projecto
            self.box_2.set('')
            self.box_2['values'] = category[self.box_3.get()]
    def save_values(self):
        '''
        Save names of Country and City
        '''
        global ProjectCode, CampaignName,df_matriz_target_aux
        Country = self.box_3.get()
        City = self.box_2.get()
        print('Country',Country)
        print('City',City)
        df_matriz_target_aux = df_matriz_target[df_matriz_target['Country'] == Country]
        if City != '':
            df_matriz_target_aux = df_matriz_target_aux[df_matriz_target_aux['City'] == City]
        #inserir data
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())            
        for index,row in df_matriz_target_aux.iterrows():
            self.tree.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))
#%%
# show window
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=Mainframe()
    app.title("APP")
    app.geometry("800x700")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: There seems like a lot of unrelated code in your question. Can you please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]? For example, is the use of a treeview and a combobox necessary or can you remove them or replace them with a label?

Comment: First you should not call `self.second_frame_outlier.pack(...)` as it is already put into the canvas using `self.my_canvas_targets.create_window(...)`.  Second you should bind `<configure>` event on `self.second_frame_outlier` instead of `self.my_canvas_targets`.

Comment: I cant reduce it otherwise I won't have the format I need for the scrollbar. ~I edited the code so you can copy it and reproduce it. Tried to change it as suggested by @acw1668 but doesn't work properly still.

Comment: *"but the buttons don't appear"*: what are those buttons?